# Replace string but preserve whitespace

Tags: regex

I want to replace a string, but preserve the outer white space, if that makes sense.

Ex:

```
" Hello world  "
```

To:

```
"  Whatever I want  "
```

I figured there was a quick way to do this via regular expressions, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby this works

```
"  this is a message   ".gsub /^(\s*)(.*?)(\s*$)/, '\1and this is another\3'
=> "  and this is another   "
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a regex that greedily matches `^\s*(.*)\s*$` and replaces the first capture group (inside the parens) should do it. But the particulars depend on the flavor of regex you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To replace `" Hello world "` to `" Whatever you Want "`, you can do something like:

```
"^\s*(.*?)\s*$"
```